# adding website to local iis. getting Server not found error

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am adding a web application to my local iis. I added the path to the folder with the bin is inside. I specified the application pool and applied my login credentials. When I hit test settings, everything passed. When I typed mysite.local on the browser, I get the following. I also clicked on Browse Website and get the same error. This is on my personal PC.

> Server not found
>
> Firefox can't find the server at www.comicrage.local.
>
> Check the address for typing errors such as ww.example.com instead of www.example.com
>       If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
>       If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: does localhost work? e.g. `http://localhost`

Answer (score 7):

Have you added **mysite.local** to the hosts file? If not, add the following to C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.local
```

The hosts file is responsible for any local overrides that should take precedence over DNS.